# Instantiating an ActionEvent with modifiers (if any)

Tags: java, actionevent

In my application when exiting it I like to prompt a little JOptionPane to assure the user wants to quits.
I've implemented the quitting behaviour with a JMenuItem and also in a MenuItem that pops-up when cliking at the TrayIcon; as well as when keying ALT+F4 or closing the main window. So, all the exit processing is done with an Action that contains the necessary actionPerformed method.
Also, the I like that the application quits without propmpting any JOptionPane if SHIFT key is pressed; so I've put this code excerpt to do this.

```
    if ((e.getModifiers() & ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) == ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) {
        abandonApplication();
    }
```

The problem I'm facing now when closing the window I need to instantiate an ActionEvent with the modifiers and I don't know how to do this. In short, what I need is this

```
private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    ExitAction.getInstance().actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(evt,ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "close", modifiers));
}
```

in a way that modifiers contains any modifier key that has been pressed (if any).

May anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Wandering arond the intenet I've found a solution that suits my needs. It's as follows:

I define an int variable intended to contain the modifiers. Then I register a Key Pressed an a Key Released listeners in such a way that the following is done:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
        modifiers = evt.getModifiers();
    }
    return;
}  

private void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
        modifiers = evt.getModifiers();
    }
    return;
}
```

So, when invoking the ExitAction I have the needed modifiers and the exit operation is done successfully in every condition (Menú Item, System Tray, ALT-F4).

I'd appreciate any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another, in my opinion better solution, I've found is when considering using key bindings. This method informs the int variable intended to contain the modifiers. I think is self-explanatory.

```
/**
 * Describes what is going to be done when SHIFT key is pressed and released
 * while the JFrame that has the focus.
 * <p>
 * When the action pressed SHIFT is detected we get the modifiers and
 * immediately disable it in order to avoid useless action executions while 
 * SHIFT key is being pressed. Alternively, when released SHIFT is detected
 * we enable pressing SHIFT action again.
 * <p>
 * In this case we get the modifiers to pass them to the action done when 
 * window closign event is detected to check if the SHIFT key is pressed to
 * force exiting of the application without prompting anything.
 */
private void shiftKeyOperation() {
    final Action shiftPressedAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            modifiers = ae.getModifiers();
            setEnabled(false);
        }
    };

    final Action shiftReleasedAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            modifiers = ae.getModifiers();
            shiftPressedAction.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    JRootPane jRootPane = getRootPane(); //here we get the RootFrame from the JFrame
    ActionMap actionMap = jRootPane.getActionMap();
    InputMap inputMap = jRootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    final String SHIFT_KEY_PRESSED_ACTION = "shift_key_pressed";
    actionMap.put(SHIFT_KEY_PRESSED_ACTION, shiftPressedAction);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), SHIFT_KEY_PRESSED_ACTION);
    final String SHIFT_KEY_RELEASED_ACTION = "shift_key_released";
    actionMap.put(SHIFT_KEY_RELEASED_ACTION, shiftReleasedAction);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, 0, true), SHIFT_KEY_RELEASED_ACTION);
    return;
}
```